# Reading kernel mode registry accesses?

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

I can do this for user mode, but how would one monitor kernel mode registry accesses at a high level description? Someone once mentioned writing some sort of driver (which wasnt really a driver) to access that low down in the OS?? :s

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve. This sounds like a heavyweight solution to whatever your underlying problem is. Perhaps there is something simpler.

Comment: I just want to be able to monitor kernel-mode registry acceses. In the past i was only able to monitor user-mode accesses.

Comment: Why do you want to do this? What is the underlying problem as opposed to the solution that you have thought of?

Comment: I'm interested in real-time stuff, so picked this as a hobby project to do....

Answer (score 2):

To do this from the kernel mode, you need to write a driver which registers callback with Configuration manager(This modules handles all the registry access from user mode and kernel mode). Once the callback is registerd successfully. Call to registry function from user mode(RegXXX) and kernel mode (ZwRegXX) will go to CM, which inturn calls your callback, if you have registerd for that specific function. Your callbacks can be registerd as Pre and Post function for different registery operation(create, open, read, write etc.).

Check http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff545879(v=VS.85).aspx for further information